# Creating a Tumbling Window for a Flink table

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm trying to create a [tubmbling window](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/table/tableapi/#tumble-tumbling-windows) for a Flink table in Java and query data for that window

```
Table table = tEnv.sqlQuery(query.getQuery());
// create a new column 'EventTime' of type Timestamp from 'EventTimetamp' which is a string
table = table.addColumns($("EventTimestamp").toTimestamp().as("EventTime"));
WindowGroupedTable windowedTable = table.window(Tumble.over("10.minutes").on($("EventTime").proctime())
    .as("w"))
    .groupBy($("w"), $("GroupingColumn"));
table = windowedTable.select($("*"));
```

However, I'm getting this error `Expected LocalReferenceExpression. Got: EventTime` when it tries to execute `windowedTable.select($("*"))`. Does anyone know what this error means and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with .addColumns($("EventTimestamp") .
addCoumns() takes an expression as input. Take a look at the example from docs.

```
Table orders = tableEnv.from("Orders");
Table result = orders.addColumns(concat($("c"), "sunny"));
```

In this example, the column "c" already exists and you tell flink to concatane the value in column "c" with string "sunny" and add the new value as a new column.

So the meaning of your code

```
table.addColumns($("EventTimestamp")
```

in English is "select EventTimeStamp from table and add the values as a new column"
As your table does not have a column "EventTimestamp" yet, expression $("EventTimestamp") returns error.

**EDIT**: The problem might be related about ROWTIME. Please take a look at my answer [using-tumble-failing-on-timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74538603/1867205)

```
        Table tableCpuDataCalculatedTemp = tableEnv.fromDataStream(streamCPUData, Schema.newBuilder()
                        .column("deviceId", DataTypes.STRING())
                        .column("cpuUsageAvarage", DataTypes.DOUBLE())
                        .column("cpuLoad15Average", DataTypes.DOUBLE())
                        .column("recordCount", DataTypes.INT())
                        .column("time_Insert_ts", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3))
                        .watermark("time_Insert_ts", "time_Insert_ts")
                        .build());
```

Comment: I have an existing column named `EventTimestamp` in my table, and the issue is not with adding a new column, I have confirmed by printing the table schema that the new column i.e. `EventTime` is added to the table.

The problem is that after creating the tumbling window, when I call `windowedTable.select($("*"));`  it throws this exception `Expected LocalReferenceExpression. Got: EventTime`

Comment: Can you put the schema here.

Comment: A column should be marked as ROWTIME. I `ve edited my original answer and added a link. Please check.

Comment: Do you know how to do this directly on an existing Flink Table object instead of creating a new Table (or in a datastream)?

Comment: please take a look at .watermark() method. It can be applied on an existing table I think. I editted my original answer too.